# How to access another Class from another Package into a GWT Vaadin Project?

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I have some problems to access a Class from another Class with different Packages in my GWT Project. My Project Structure looks like this:

```
++ src/main/java
   ++ fr.myProj.common.kit
        ++ myGenClass.java
   ...
   ++ fr.myProj.common.kit.gwt.client.ui.widgets
        ++ myUiClass.java

++ src/main/resources
   ++ de
       ++ myProj
           ++ common
              ++ kit
                  ++ public
                  AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml
```

I call into **`myUiClass.java`** an instance of **`myGenClass.java`** without problems but when i compile **`AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml`** GWT give me an error : `No source code is available for type fr.myProj.common.kit.myGenClass; did you forget to inherit a required module?`

How can i resolve this issue?

**EDIT:**

using `<inherit name="fr.myProj.common.kit.myGenClass">` dont work either!!

**EDIT 2:**

and giving  `fr.myProj.common.kit` its own `kit.gwt.xml` like [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWTModules/article.html) shows dont work too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have changed the default location of gwt module file it will not work as expected.

AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml is under kit and there is no client folder in the same space. You need to explicitly specify your source paths for gwt. In this case move AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml **one level up into common** and then add source tag for kit folder.
`<source path="kit"></source>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the required modules in *.gwt.xml (could be AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml in your case) file:

`<inherits name="module_name"/>`

Also, please note that in GWT, Java code is translated to Javascript. So, some of the classes that work with a JVM may not work with GWT.

Comment: Thanks SwapnilS but i already try this and its not works... by the way... the Java code im trying to add is my Own java Classes... and all imports are working with GWT.